# Is it possible to create JSON strings from a pipe using jq?

Tags: jq

Let's say I use the command `find "$HOME" -maxdepth 1 -type d` and I get the following result:

```
/home/user/folder1
/home/user/folder2
/home/user/folder3
/home/user/folder4
```

I'd like to use `jq` on a pipe and create different JSON lines as the following:

```json
{ "path": "/home/user/folder1", "type":"directory"}
{ "path": "/home/user/folder2", "type":"directory"}
{ "path": "/home/user/folder3", "type":"directory"}
{ "path": "/home/user/folder4", "type":"directory"}
```

I expected to solve it with `jq` to avoid putting this list of folders inside an array and creating them one by one in a loop. In pseudo-code the idea would be:

```bsh
find "$HOME" -maxdepth 1 -type d | jq '.logic-to-create-json-strings'
```

Is it possible to do with `jq`?

Comment: JSON cannot represent arbitrary file paths (which are sequences of bytes other than zero) in its strings which are sequences of UTF-8 encoded characters. Also note that [the output of `find` is not post-processable](/q/321697) unless you use `-print0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer assumes that your filenames (or whatever text you wish to JSON encode) is valid UTF-8.

Two alternatives:

Not using `xargs`:    Call `jq` with the pathnames as positional parameters directly from `find` with `-exec`.  Read the found pathnames with `--args` and access them as the array `$ARGS.positional` in the `jq` expression.  For each pathname, create a JSON object.

```bash
find "$HOME" -maxdepth 1 -type d \
    -exec jq -n -c \
      '$ARGS.positional[] as $path | { path: $path, type: "directory" }' \
      --args {} +
```

Using `xargs`:  Use `-print0` with `find` and `-0` with `xargs` to safely pass the found pathnames from `find` to `xargs`. The `jq` expression is identical to the above, only how the pathnames are passed between `find` and `jq` differs.

```bash
find "$HOME" -maxdepth 1 -type d -print0 |
xargs -0 jq -n -c \
  '$ARGS.positional[] as $path | { path: $path, type: "directory" }' --args
```

With both approaches above, `jq` would encode the found pathnames so that they can be represented as JSON strings.

An alternative `jq` expression, with the same effect as

```
$ARGS.positional[] as $path | { path: $path, type: "directory" }
```

is

```
$ARGS.positional | map({ path: ., type: "directory" })[]
```

---

To read *lines* into a set of objects as you show, you may use the following `jq` command, which reads from its standard input stream:

```bash
jq -R -c '{ path: ., type: "directory" }'
```

Comment: That only works if file paths are valid UTF-8 encoded text. Each byte that cannot be decoded into a UTF-8 character by `jq` would be changed into the `�` character.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Noted, thanks.

Comment: @Kusalananda I've just realized that the output of `find` also prints the current folder when I execute it as I did in my example. So `/home/user` ends up being included on the list. One workaround that I thought was using  `find "$HOME/" -maxdepth 1 -type d -print0 | grep -v '^/.*/$'` for differentiating the actual folder with a final `/`... But it doesn't seem like an ideal solution. Do you know if there's any `find` parameter to handle not showing the current folder as well?

Comment: Ah, I found it... I should be using `find "$HOME" -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -print0`... Just adding `-mindepth 1` solved it!

Comment: @raylight Yeah, that or `! -path "$HOME"` before `-print0` or `-exec`.

Answer (score 2):

JSON cannot directly represent arbitrary file paths (which are sequences of bytes other than zero) in its strings which are sequences of UTF-8 encoded characters. Also note that [the output of `find` is not post-processable](/q/321697) unless you use `-print0`.

For instance a file path might be `$'/home/St\xc3\xa9phane\nChazelas/ISO-8859-1/R\xe9sum\xe9'` (here using `ksh93`-style `$'...'` notation to represent byte values), with a `é` UTF-8 encoded in `Stéphane`, and ISO-8859-1 encoded in `Résumé`.

JSON cannot represent that file path unless you use some encoding. That could be for instance URI encoding:

```
{ "path": "/home/St%C3%A9phane\nChazelas/ISO-8859-1/R%E9sum%E9" }
```

Another approach could be to interpret the path as if it were ISO-8859-1 encoded (or any single-byte charset where any byte value can make a valid character¹):

```
{ "path": "/home/StÃ©phane\nChazelas/ISO-8859-1/Résumé" }
```

`jq` has some support for doing URI encoding, but AFAIK cannot be fed non-UTF-8 input. AFAIK, it doesn't have any support for encoding conversion either.

On a GNU system, for the second approach where file paths are considered to be ISO-8859-1 encoded you may however be able to do something like:

```
find ~ -type d -print0 |
  iconv -f iso-8859-1 -t utf-8 |
  tr '\0\n' '\n\0' |
  jq -Rc '{"path":sub("\u0000";"\n"),"type":"directory"}'
```

Which on our example above gives:

```
{"path":"/home/StÃ©phane\nChazelas/ISO-8859-1/Résumé.pdf","type":"directory"}
```

---

<sup>¹ though iso-8859-1 specifically is an obvious choice as its code points match those of Unicode. So if your json string contains a U+00E9 character for instance, you know it corresponds to the 0xE9 byte. You could add the `-a` option to `jq` for non-ASCII characters to be represented as `\uXXXX` instead.</sup>